# In swift, how to manage two buttons in same custom tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to manage two buttons in same custom tableview cell.
Added two buttons named Yes and No. If yes button is selected the No button will be inactive and Yes button became active.

Here is the image what I need

[image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.yesButton.tag = 101
    cell.noButton.tag = 102
    cell.yesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    cell.noButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

 @objc func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableList)
    let indexPath = tableList.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    if sender.tag == 101 {
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("Cell indexpath = \(String(describing: indexPath?.row))")
        }
    }

    if sender.tag == 102 {
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("Cell indexpath = \(String(describing: indexPath?.row))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Strictly spoken you don't use a *custom* table view cell. You are using a standard table view cell with custom objects. Don't do that. Design a table view cell with **real** `custom` style and with a custom class containing `IBOutlets`. In this cell you can implement the custom logic to control the buttons. Dealing with tags to identify UI elements is outdated for a long time.

Comment: You can use enum's with your tags e.g
enum SenderTags: Int  { 
case foo = 101,
case foo2 = 102
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a model to main the state of yesButton and noButton for each tableViewCell, i.e.

```
class Model {
    var isYesSelected = false
    var isNoSelected = false
}
```

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` with `Outlets` of `yesButton` and `noButton`.

Create a single `@IBAction` for both the `buttons` and handle their UI based on which `button` is tapped.

Also, use a `buttonTapHandler` to identify the `row` in which the `button` is tapped. It will be called everytime a `button` is tapped. We'll be setting this when creating the instance of `TableViewCell` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var yesButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var noButton: UIButton!

    var buttonTapHandler: (()->())?
    var model: Model?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        yesButton.backgroundColor = .gray
        noButton.backgroundColor = .gray
    }

    func configure(with model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        self.updateUI()
    }

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        model?.isYesSelected = (sender == yesButton)
        model?.isNoSelected = !(sender == yesButton)
        self.updateUI()
    }

    func updateUI() {
        yesButton.backgroundColor = (model?.isYesSelected ?? false) ? .green : .gray
        noButton.backgroundColor = (model?.isNoSelected ?? false) ? .green : .gray
    }
}
```

`UITableViewDataSource's` `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method goes like,

```
let numberOfCells = 10
var models = [Model]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    (0..<numberOfCells).forEach { _ in
        self.models.append(Model())
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfCells
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.configure(with: models[indexPath.row])
    cell.buttonTapHandler = {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
    return cell
}
```

To get the `totalPoints`, count the `models` with `isYesSelected = true`, i.e.

```
let totalPoints = models.reduce(0) { (result, model) -> Int in
    if model.isYesSelected {
        return result + 1
    }
    return 0
}
print(totalPoints)
```

Comment: this should have a model table cells are dequeued

Comment: @Sh_Khan Didn't get you. Please explain.

Comment: Also, there is nothing specified like the OP wants to save that state anywhere.

Comment: @PGDev The button colour changes when we scroll the table.

Comment: Then you must maintain it in the model. And you should clarify that in the question itself.

Comment: @PGDev Could you please help me to complete this task?
I need to select yes or no answers and show the total points.
if Yes - 1 Point

The table list is dynamic. Can't predict the cell count .

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: @PGDev Do you have any idea about the total point calculation?

Comment: What exactly is not working? And where have you added the code for calculating the totalPoints?

Comment: The bug is in table scrolling.  the button colour changes

Comment: Updated the code. There was a mistake in the code. I edited that. It should work now.

Comment: Do accept(tick on left) if the answer helped you. Happy coding 

Answer (score 0):

Get that Button using your Tag like below and after that, you can change the value as per you want.

```
var tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tmpTag) as? UIButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple 3 step process...!!

1. Define Model Class
2. Prepare tableView Cell & handle actions
3. Set up tableView in view controller

Let's start implementation:

**1) Define Model Class**

In UI, we have a information like question & it's answer (Yes/No). So design model respectively.

```
//MARK:- Class Declaration -
class Question {
      let questionText: String
      var answerState: Bool?

      init(question: String) {
           self.questionText = question
      }
}
```

**2. Prepare tableView Cell & handle actions**

Create a custom tableView cell with **Question Label**, **Yes Button** & **No Button**. Link that view with respected @IBOutlets & @IBActions.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
      @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var yesButton: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var noButton: UIButton!

      var question: Question?
      var toggle: Bool? {
          didSet {
                 question?.answerState = toggle
                 //Do buttons operations like...
                 if let isToggle = toggle {
                    yesButton.backgroundColor = isToggle ? .green : .gray
                    noButton.backgroundColor = isToggle ? .gray : .green
                 } else {
                    yesButton.backgroundColor =  .gray
                    noButton.backgroundColor = .gray
                 }
          }
      }

      func prepareView(forQuestion question: Question) {
           self.question = question
           questionLabel.text = question.questionText
           toggle = question.answerState
      }

      //Yes Button - IBAction Method
      @IBAction func yesButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            toggle = true
      }

      //No Button - IBAction Method
      @IBAction func noButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            toggle = false
      }
}
```

**3. Set up tableView in view controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //Prepare questions model array to design our tableView data source
    let arrQuestions: [Question] = [Question(question: "Do you speak English?"), Question(question: "Do you live in Chicago?")]
}

//MARK:- UITableView Data Source & Delegate Methods -
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrQuestions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as? TableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        tableViewCell.prepareView(forQuestion: arrQuestions[indexPath.row])
        return tableViewCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- Create basic tableView and configure dataSource functions
  [image: image1]
- Create tableView cell with two buttons
  [image: image2]
- Create cell class with buttons outlets and actions
  [image: image3]
- Result of this code

[image: result gif]

Enjoy!